# I want to access asynchronously stored data in a child component from the parent component in Vue 3

Tags: vuejs3

I am not good at English. Please understand.
receive data asynchronously from subcomponents in vue3 and store it in the store
After checking the stored values in the parent component
I want to set isLoad to true, but I can't detect it even if I use watch, watchEffect.
What's the problem?

App.vue

```
const commonStore = useCommonStore();
const storeRef = storeToRefs(commonStore);
watchEffect(() => {
  if (state.value.data1.value !== null && state.value.data2.value !== null) {
    isLoad.value = true;
    // console.log('true', isLoad.value);
  } else {
    console.log('false', isLoad.value);
  }
});


<template>   
     <Component1 />
      <Component2 />
</template>
```

store.vue

```
export const useCommonStore = () => {

  const state = {
    data1: ref(null),
    data2: ref(null),
    isDataLoaded: ref(false),
  };

  const stateInfo = computed(()=>state)
  const getterIsDataLoaded = computed(()=>state.isDataLoaded.value)

  const setData1 = (data: any) => {
    state.data1.value = data;
  };

  const setData2 = (data: any) => {
    state.data2.value = data;
  };

  const resolveIsDataLoaded = (data:any) => {
    state.isDataLoaded.value = data;
  };


  return {
    state,
    stateInfo,
    setData1,
    setData2,
    getterIsDataLoaded,
    resolveIsDataLoaded
  };
};
```

Comment: Either emit an event from the child and handle it in the parent, or use a shared datastore like Pinia.

Answer (score 0):

Im lacking of Information about the Store type (Vuex / pinia) but I still can direct you to the soltuion.

Firstly I would recommned that check the assigned variable of the loading, in the App.vue you are setting the **"isLoad.value"** and in the Store you have a state attribute that named **"isDataLoaded"**.

Moreover, The `const storeRef = storeToRefs(commonStore);` I would change to :

```
const {data1, data2, isDataLoaded} = storeToRefs(commonStore);
```

Then You can use them as you would like inside the wanted scenario.

*Beaware that its recommended to change the State in Pinia only within an Action callback such as :

```
setData1(data1) {
  this.data1 = data1;
},
```

And also to get the State by a Getter function :

```
getData1: (state) => state.data1,
```

This is the more cleaner way, hope it helps :)